# Boot from usb if available

Tags: usb, boot, bootloader, cmdline.txt

I have my raspbian OS located on a 3TB external harddrive only some bootmanager stuff left on the SD Card. (if i remember right i followed this [guide](http://www.raspipress.com/2013/05/install-and-run-raspbian-from-a-usb-flash-drive/))

I want it to boot from the sd card ONLY if there is no USB Drive available to boot from.
I edited the *cmdline.txt* file which is containing the following by default `root=/dev/mmcblk0p2`
to `root=/dev/sda2`.

Can i add some BASH logic in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not simple to achieve.

`cmdline.txt` contains kernel arguments and one of them is `root=` argument. There is no way to achieve simple failover as `root=` accepts only one device.

My suggestion is to make two SD cards, one with `root=/dev/mmcblk0p2` and one with `root=/dev/sda1` and switch them based on what you plug in.

Another solution, also good one, is that you always boot from SD card `root=/dev/mmcblk0p2` and put your `/dev/sda1` into `/etc/fstab` so it mounts on `/mnt` on boot, if it is plugged in.

Comment: the last solution is not really satisfying for me because the OS is then run on the SD Card. I moved the OS to the Hard Drive to prevent SD Card Corruption and i was told it runs more stable.
So I guess i'd have to go with two seperate SD Cards .. thanks for explaining the cmdline.txt though.

Answer (score 0):

There is no seperate BIOS hidden on the Pi == the SD card IS the BIOS and system 'all in one'.

However, since the SD will always be present, it should be quite possible to have it 'cross boot' to the external hard drive (after loading the GPIO 'blob' & uSB 'drivers') .. in 'nix world, go look up GRUB ...